# Is it a good idea to collapse old rails migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

A rails app I am developing currently has about 35 migrations up to this point. Since the application started as an experiment, there is a fair amount of meaningless churn in the migrations as I went back and forth between different ideas.

Are there any drawbacks to collapsing migrations 1-35 into one migration? I was planning to do this by having the first migration load the schema as it is now and deleting all the previous migrations.

I am currently the only person working on this project, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have your code under source control (you *do* have your code under source control, don't you?) then I'd say there's no real harm, provided you accept that rolling back schema changes is going to require either restoration of old migrations or brand new migrations. Just be sure you understand the implications and accept them before setting anything in stone.

Your current schema.rb can form the basis of a new single migration that will start a new set.

Be warned that if you have data manipulation operations in your existing migrations, static data loads, for example, and/or possible subsequent transformations, then these will need to be handled somewhere. It's something I've tripped over a few times...

Answer (score 6):

I would keep them around. Don't worry about having to run lots of migrations everytime a new developer checks out the project. He can always run

```
rake db:schema:load
```

which is much faster, instead of running

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes migrations may use models that no longer exist or create tables and then later on destroy them, wasting precious CPU time. Best to compile it all into *db/schema.rb* and get your developers to run `rake db:schema:load`

Answer (score 2):

If all your migrations do is modify your table structures I wouldn't worry about it all.

Keep in mind though that some migrations add data - I have ones that seed the database with an admin account and other fixed data - and the schema won't give you this.

Mind you it is a bad idea to do what I do with migrations since I don't use the migrations in deployment.  So collapsing migrations might be a good idea for a time to move those data seeding migrations to separate rake tasks.

On review - I am echoing points already made.  `rake db:migrate VERSION -1`

[I blame the distracting new animated logo for drawing my eye away from the text]

Answer (score 1):

No harm, and collapsing migrations is a good practice and helps performance when migrations do need to be run.  This is now part of Rails' schema.rb:

```
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
```

Note as @mike-woodhouse says, "Be warned that if you have data manipulation operations in your existing migrations, static data loads, for example, and/or possible subsequent transformations, then these will need to be handled somewhere."

But you shouldn't be doing any of that in your migrations anyway :)
-- Chad

Answer (score -1):

For those that, like me, found this answer in search for a way to **reset an application back to its original state**, here is what to do:

```
rm db/migrations/*
rake db:drop
rake db:schmea:dump
```

This is useful if you've just started an app and decided you want to rebuild it from scratch without losing all your files.